# pass a paramter to a script through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, parameters

I am able to execute script through .htaccess but I would like to pass a parameter to this script Is there a way to pass input parameter to a script in .htaccess?
I am not able to set environment variable and use it inside the script.
Is it possible to use environment variable defined in .htaccess in a script?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new.sh [E=VAR:$1,L]
```

I would like to pass VAR parameter to new.sh script
to be executed like `new.sh VAR`

Comment: Please post a sample of what you've been working with to help us gain some context and better understand your needs. Thanks :-)

Comment: I updated the question. I woulk like to execute "new.sh VAR"

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass it as a query string.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new.sh?VAR=$1 [E=VAR:$1,L]
```

Or, since it's being set as an environment variable, read the current environment variables from inside of your script; i.e., `VAR` has been set as an environment variable in your example.

Comment: What scripting language are you using in that `.sh` file?

Comment: I am using #!/bin/bash